# Is there any way to get a meteorite if there's no Corruption or Crimson in the world?

Tags: terraria

What do I do if my world has no corruption or crimson whatsoever? Is there any other way to have meteorite fall?

Comment: Every world should have either corruption or crimson (not both) in it somewhere.  Make sure you explore from ocean-to-ocean before discounting any existing on your map.  Some worlds have multiples on both sides of spawn, others have very little.

Answer (score 4):

If your world doesn't have either, someone probably cleansed it all so look for chasms with stone walls. You should be able to find crimson hearts or shadow orbs at the bottom to get a meteor to spawn. If you really can't find anything that even looks like it was corrupted before, you cannot get a meteor to spawn. I would check with a map editor to be sure, though, before generating a new world.

Answer (score 3):

Just to double check, you should download a map editor or viewer like [terrafirma](http://seancode.com/terrafirma/) to make sure you don't have any corruption or crimson. After you have checked and there has been no sign of the previously stated biomes then you either must look for terrain that looks similar to the biomes and explore there (If lady luck is smiling at you, you will find either a shadow orb or a heart) or make a new world entirely. Sadly, there is no other way to summon a meteorite :(

Answer (score 3):

If your ultimate goal is just to farm the ore, you could import 50 meteorite ore from another world and place it anywhere you like.  This will cause Meteor Heads to spawn, which can drop ore.  Just make sure it is all kept in the same area (on one screen).  You will know you've done it right when the Meteorite Biome music starts to play.

Answer (score 0):

Meteors do not require destroying shadow orbs to spawn. This is just the most efficient method for getting a meteor to spawn. There is a small random chance that every sunset a meteor will come crashing down.

Comment: The small random chance only appears after you break the first orb/heart.

Comment: Ah, I though there was always a chance.